# Is there a Vue way of creating a drag ghost image?

Tags: vue.js, drag-and-drop

I need to create a custom ghost image for a dragged element. And also I need to change it's style a bit. This is my code:

```
   const onDragStart = (e) => {
      const ghost = e.target.cloneNode(true);
    
      ghost.setAttribute("id", "ghost");
    
      ghost.style.position = "absolute";
      ghost.style.right = "-999px";
    
      // counter is an element that should not be displayed on a ghost image
      ghost.getElementsByClassName("counter")[0].remove();
    
      document.body.appendChild(ghost);
    
      e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(ghost, 20, 20);
    };
    
    const onDragEnd = () => {
      const ghost = document.getElementById("ghost");
    
      if (ghost) {
        ghost.remove();
      }
    };
```

Since I use Vue, manipulating DOM directly seems like a bad idea. Is there any way to do the same result, but in a Vue-way?

Comment: Aren't they any Vue plugins that could do that for you already?

Comment: @kissu maybe, but not allowed to use any third-party libraries

Comment: You'll get a harder time trying to do something the Vue way without using Vue plugins.

Comment: @kissu I guess... I tried to create a specal component for a ghost image. But it's such a headache to work with it